# Como usar long2ip en una consulta php, uso CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php7, codeigniter-4

Tengo este código en un modelo personalizado en CodeIgniter 4, necesito saber como puedo usar la función long2ip para obtener un ip (IPv4) valido, en la base de datos ya he guardado el registro con ip2long y funciona de maravilla.

```php
$builder = $this->db->table('tb_direccionamiento');
$builder->join('tb_area', 'tb_direccionamiento.id_a = tb_area.id_a', 'left');
$builder->select('*');
$builder->select(long2ip("ip"));
$builder->orderBy('ip', 'ASC');
$posts = $builder->get()->getResultArray();
return $posts;
```

Y el error que pone en la consola del navegador es el siguiente

> message   "long2ip() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given"

saludos de antemano

Comment: perfecto Sal, me devulve ip (IPv4) valido, pero solo eso, tambien necesito el resto de los campos a mostar, sabes como ¿? y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No llames `long2ip()` en `$builder`; aplica la función a cada sub-elemento:

```
$posts = $builder->get()->getResultArray();
$posts = array_map( function($v){ 
                       $v['ip'] = long2ip($v['ip']);
                       return $v; 
                    }
                  , $posts
                  );
return $posts;
```

O de una forma mas tradicional:

```
$posts = $builder->get()->getResultArray();
foreach( $posts as &$post )
   $post['ip'] = long2ip($post['ip']);
return $posts;
```

Comment: un millon de gracias pero forma mas tradicional no me funciono, la primera parte si, 100%, agradecido